# Prevent internet access except for one server?

Tags: networking, proxy, routing, linux-networking

I want to see if the HTTP proxy support for an application is working correctly. In order to check this I have installed a Ubuntu VirtualBox on my Mac laptop and I want to configure the virtual machine so that it has no access to any other internet host except my test proxy server.

How can I configure the virtual machine? From what I've read it sounds like "route add ..." should be able to do it but I'm not sure exactly how to use it.

Please advise! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for iptables and firewall rules. Could work like that

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

But keep in mind, this will block ALL other traffic, so you'll need to have console access to the machine. and replace 192.168.0.1 with the proxy IP for sure.

If the proxy server is also the gateway you can also add the port to the 2nd iptables statement p.e. -p 3128 for squid proxy so the server can only connect to the port.
2nd you also have to keep in mind, that DNS requests will be blocked as well, to enable them you'll need to add a second rule to enable DNS requests

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.1 -p 3128 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.1 -p 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do following things :

- Set environment variable, provided that you are talking only about HTTP proxy

> http_proxy="http://username:password@host:port" ; export http_proxy

- Route all traffic through some host on the IP level with route

> route add default gw 12.12.12.12

where 12.12.12.12 should be substituted by your gateway ip address that has it's proxy server running at.

- Drop all traffic to other hosts, but your database with iptables